# Ground not displaying in HTML5 canvas game - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I'm working on an HTML5 canvas game using JavaScript, and I'm facing an issue where the ground is not displaying. I've created a Ground class to represent the ground tiles, and I'm instantiating them in a loop in the start function. Despite this, the ground is not rendering on the canvas.

Here is important part of my code:

```
class Ground {
    constructor(x, num, src) {
        this.canvas = canvas;
        this.context = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
        this.ground = new Image();
        this.ground.src = src;
        this.width = this.ground.width;
        this.height = this.ground.height;
        this.position = {
            x: (x + this.width) * num,
            y: this.canvas.height - this.width,
        };
    }

    create() {
        let context = this.context;
        context.drawImage(this.ground, this.position.x, this.position.y, this.width, this.height);
    }
}

const canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas');
canvas.style.background = "#f9f9f9";
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

const ground = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    let src = 'src/Tiles/Tile (2).png';
    ground[i] = new Ground(0, i, src);
}

let start = () => {
    requestAnimationFrame(start);

    ground.forEach(ground => {
        ground.create();
        if (player.position.y + player.height <= ground.position.y && player.position.y + player.height + player.velocity.y >= ground.position.y && player.position.x + player.width >= ground.position.x && player.position.x <= ground.position.x + ground.width) {
            player.velocity.y = 0;
            doJump = true;
        }
        zombies.forEach(zombie => {
            if (zombie.position.y + zombie.height <= ground.position.y && zombie.position.y + zombie.height + zombie.velocity.y >= ground.position.y && zombie.position.x + zombie.width >= ground.position.x && zombie.position.x <= ground.position.x + ground.width) {
                zombie.velocity.y = 0;
            }
        });
    });
}

start();
```

I've checked the Ground class constructor, the ground's position calculation, and the rendering loop, but I can't identify the issue. The canvas background is showing, and other game elements are rendering correctly.

Can someone please help me troubleshoot why the ground is not displaying?

Comment: You need to wait for the image to load. Listen to the Image `"load"` event to know when the image has loaded. BTW there is no need to load the same image 100 times. Load it once and use the same image in each `Ground` object etc.. This question will likely be flagged as a duplicate as there are many questions with answers related to loading images.

Comment: Ya I know there are many Q/A which is relevant to images load, but In my case there is no issue with image load because when I console.log the path and click on it. It shows the image.

Comment: It is not *"If the image loads"*, it is  *"How long it takes to load."* and trying to load the same image 100 times is not helping either.

Comment: @Blindman67 I tried but it didn't worked.